# Como fazer duas sessionStorages

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo um sistema de testes com uma API e estou usando javascript puro para a integração via AJAX. Estou armazenando os dados em local e sessionStorage para transitar entre as páginas. O meu problema é o seguinte:

Eu armazeno os dados de uma categoria no sessionStorage e quando faço um outro código para armazenar dados de um outro objeto no sessionStorage, ele não cria a nova sessão. É assim mesmo ou tem uma forma de criar duas sessões?

Comment: Eu gostaria de ver os métodos que você está utilizando pra gravar a sessão.

Comment: window.sessionStorage.setItem('categoria', xhr.responseText);

Comment: window.sessionStorage.setItem('categoriaA',"conteudo A");
window.sessionStorage.setItem('categoriaB',"conteudo B");
console.log('window.sessionStorage');

Retornou os dois normalmente:
window.sessionStorage.length; //2

Acredito que tenha algum parametro errado na função que você criou, daí só vendo o código mesmo